# In selenium Webdriver, Not able to verify auto-updated State and City field after entering the zip code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I have a Zip Code input box, once I enter the Zip Code, the state and city input boxes auto-populate with the relevant data.
how do we capture or validate those State and city input box values?

This is code:

```
WebElement selectZipcode = pp.getZipcodeField();
Thread.sleep(2000);
selectZipcode.sendKeys("40007");
Thread.sleep(2000);
selectZipcode.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(2000);
selectZipcode.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(2000);
AssertJUnit.assertEquals(pp.getStateField().getText(), "Kentucky");
```

Comment: Share the URL, also whether it is drop-down or Text box

Comment: Share the `HTML` source for the elements

Comment: Assuming it's an input with type='text'.. You might try with getProperty('value') method of the element.  (it's part of the W3C spec, though not real clear if all current drivers support it...)  Otherwise, execute javascript to get the value. Ex:  var x = document.getElementById("StateFieldID").value;